# How were these total contained resources calculated?

Tags: chemistry

I'm an investor trying to understand the technical document of a mining resource.

If a mining report listed its indicated resources as:

- 25.59 Mt (meaning Million Tons)
- 1711 ppm

How is the contained resource in lbs determined?

The resource is Uranium, but contained lbs should be in U3O8 as 1 lb. U in U3O8 = 1.17924 lbs. U3O8.

The report states that the contained resource is 96.5 Mlbs of U3O8 but I'm not sure how they arrived there. I am interseted in the math, not necessarily the resource in questions.

Comment: Since you tagged this [tag:Chemistry], I want to you ask are you really an investor or this is just a part of a question?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Yea I have a MEng in CS, I make more money than I have bills, so I want to make that money grow outside of my lazy IRA and 401k portfolios. If you want to read about the Grade-Tonnage report, you can [here](https://www.globalatomiccorp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/NI-43-101-MRE-31-July-2019.pdf). I tagged `chemistry` because this site doesn't let me tag `algebra` on its own, and that was the closest related topic.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri The particular table with values is on Page 14.

Comment: Cool. They have only multiplied the two quantities and converted to lbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1711$ parts per million (i.e. tons per million tons assuming weight/weight PPM) and you have $25.59$ million tons, so tons of $U_{308}$ present is $1711\times 25.59$ which is $1711\times 25.59\times 1000\text{ kg}=43.78\times10^6\text{ kg}$. Convert this to $\text{lbs}$ to get the desired value $96.53$ million tons.

Comment: Why did you use 1000 kg?

Comment: A ton is $1000$ kg. You could just directly convert ton to lbs, but I figured kg to lbs calculators would be more widespread and common.